# Why do statistical physics and thermodynamics care about fluctuations?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fluctuation-dissipation

Fluctuation seems to be an eternal theme in the study of statistical physics and thermodynamics, why do we need to care about it? Just for stability?
Any comments would be appreciated

Comment: If you actually do experiments, dealing with the fluctuations is a huge part of your work.

Comment: Those fluctuations are why, say, crystallization from the melt happens.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer are the Green Kubo relations. By calculating the fluctuations, you can deduce the system’s response when varying parameters. For example, fluctuations in energy will characterize how energy changes with temperature (heat capacity) or fluctuation in magnetization determines how magnetization changes with an external field (susceptibility).

On a more practical level, the study of fluctuations can model the noise which typically spoils measurement. It can therefore be used to characterize the fundamental limits of the precision of certain methods and point to alternative routes to improve them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sometimes the noise *is* the measurement. For example, temperature from antenna voltage fluctuations.